# Python - Scrapy Javascript Pagination (next_page)

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

i made this script for this website....but my pagination doesn't work because its just javascript...and when you click nextpage the container loads new data....
i did found the urls for the naxt pages, here's some examples:

[Page2](https://www.siriocenter.gr/Proionta/Mpoulonia-ApostatesTroxwn#modelStr=%7B%22VehicleBrandId%22%3A%22%22,%22VehicleYear%22%3A%22%22,%22VehicleModelId%22%3A%22%22,%22VehicleId%22%3A%22%22,%22AntallaktikoCategoryId%22%3A%22%22,%22AntallaktikoProductTypeId%22%3A%22%22,%22AntallaktikoKareId%22%3A%22%22,%22ProductBrandId%22%3A%22%22,%22sortProperty%22%3A%22ItemPrice%22,%22sortDirection%22%3A%22Ascending%22,%22pageNo%22%3A%221%22,%22pageSize%22%3A%2210%22%7D)

[Page3](https://www.siriocenter.gr/Proionta/Mpoulonia-ApostatesTroxwn#modelStr=%7B%22VehicleBrandId%22%3A%22%22,%22VehicleYear%22%3A%22%22,%22VehicleModelId%22%3A%22%22,%22VehicleId%22%3A%22%22,%22AntallaktikoCategoryId%22%3A%22%22,%22AntallaktikoProductTypeId%22%3A%22%22,%22AntallaktikoKareId%22%3A%22%22,%22ProductBrandId%22%3A%22%22,%22sortProperty%22%3A%22ItemPrice%22,%22sortDirection%22%3A%22Ascending%22,%22pageNo%22%3A%222%22,%22pageSize%22%3A%2210%22%7D)

But im getting the results from the first page only....:/, i was thinking to use scrapy-splash but im not sure if that will work....

here's is my test code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import time

class SiriosbotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'SiriosBot'
    start_urls = ['https://www.siriocenter.gr/Proionta/Mpoulonia-ApostatesTroxwn']
    def parse(self, response):
        for content in response.css('div.resultItemTxt'):
            item = {
            'Title' : content.css('th[colspan="2"] > a::text').extract(),
            'Price' : content.css('div.price > span::text').extract(),
            'Manufacture' : content.css('tr:nth-child(2)').extract(),
            'Model' : content.css('tr:nth-child(3)').extract(),
            'Eidos' : content.css('tr:nth-child(4)').extract(),
            'Typos' : content.css('tr:nth-child(5)').extract(),
            'Kare' : content.css('tr:nth-child(6)').extract(),
            'Comments' : content.css('tr:nth-child(7)').extract(),
            'ProductLink' : content.css('th[colspan="2"] > a::attr(href)').extract(),
            'Img' : content.css('div.resultItemImage > a').extract(),
            'CurrentURL' : response.url
            }
            yield item

        for next_page in response.css('div.paging > a:last-child::attr(href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(next_page.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

Comment: I'm coming here after already having answered your question at https://python-forum.io/Thread-Python-Scrapy-Javascript-Pagination-next-page Note that cross-posting your questions (posting them on multiple sites) is generally discouraged, and if you do so, you should at least let people know.

Comment: i did it because im not getting sometimes answer....so i did it to get quicker answer, sorry if that bothered you...